# Concise way to add a citation showing closely-related effects that result from one of a list of cited examples for a trend?

Tags: writing, citation-style

I have a parenthetical serial list of citations that demonstrate support for a claim I make prior to the parenthetical list.

> X has been shown to impact Y (e.g., Mo 1900, Larry 1920, Curly 1950).

I additionally want to point out an additional citation that -- although it doesn't directly show X impacts Y -- demonstrates how the impacts of one of these citations (e.g., Curly 1950) can have broader but relevant effect.

> X has been shown to impact Y (e.g., Mo 1900, Larry 1920, Curly 1950). The results of Curly (1950) may result in Z (Shemp 2000).

However, I'd like a way to say this more concisely. **Is there some form of shorthand or sentence/citation structure commonly used in manuscript writing that would allow me to combine the `Shemp` citation with the rest of the list?**

Ideally, something concise akin to the Latin *cf.*, would be ideal, though multiple words would suffice if appropriate. Something that would fill in the blank below:

> X has been shown to impact Y (e.g., Mo 1900, Larry 1920, Curly 1950, _____ Shemp 2000).

Comment: perhaps something that means "and see related" but in a way that I can associate Shemp with the effects of Curly more specifically/explicitly.

Answer (score 1):

M, L, C; see also S

M, L, C; for consequences of C see also S

M, L, C; the last of these also leads to S

But "Curly 1950" is already concise, so if you want to convey all your information you can't make it much more concise than in your version.